# can I detect whether a button click came from a label

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<label for="foo">Click me to trigger the button</label>
<button id="foo">I'm a button</button>
```

Say you have a label associated with a button like the above. Clicking on the label triggers a click on the button. Is there any way to detect from within an event handler whether the click came from the label?

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target); //is always button element.
  const labelWasClicked = ???;
  if (labelWasClicked) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: could change the selector

Answer (score 1):

Click event has `isTrusted` property, which gets `false`, if click was triggered from script. I hoped, that label-click will show false as well... but it appeared to be "true". You still can emulate the label behavior and use `isTrusted`, if it doesn't matter for other parts of the code.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let label = e.target.closest(".pseudo-label");
  if(!label) return;
  
  if( e.target.closest("#" + label.dataset.for ) ) return;
  
  document.getElementById( label.dataset.for ).click();
});

document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.isTrusted);
});
```

```css
.pseudo-label {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo-label" data-for="foo">Click me to trigger the button <button id="foo">I'm a button</button> </div>
```

But this seems useless))

You can just separate the code in two different listeners, and use a boolean variable to detect the required click:

```js
let labelClicked = false;

first('label[for="foo"]').addEventListener("click", function() {
  labelClicked = true;
  console.log("label click");
});

first("#foo").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("general click"); // You might divide this in two...
  
  if( labelClicked ) return labelClicked = false;  
  console.log("button click");  //...separate function calls.
});

/***/
function first(selector) { return document.querySelector(selector); }
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="foo">Click me to trigger the button</label>
<button id="foo">I'm a button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("[for=foo]").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target); // Fires only if you click the label
});

document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target); // Fires if you click the label or the button
});
```

```html
<label for="foo">Click me to trigger the button</label>
<button id="foo">I'm a button</button>
```

Comment: This seems potentially like it would work, although I'd have to use a boolean flag or some other state. The main thing this would hinge on is if the order of the events is consistent. Will the label click even always fire before the button click event?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the label and button in a div and fire the event on that, the event target will be the label when the label is clicked, and the button when the button is clicked, for example:

```js
document.querySelector("#myDiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('target:', e.target);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <label for="foo">Click me to trigger the button</label>
  <button id="foo">I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is because you are targeting the DOM element with id="foo".

```
var labelID;

$('label').click(function() {
       labelID = $(this).attr('for');
       $('#'+labelID).trigger('click');
});
```

[from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/click-input-when-label-clicked/)

Comment: OP is using vanilla JS not jQuery

Comment: This JS is unnecessary, since the for attribute adds this behavior by default.